# Unable to automatically locate the Ansys path for version 221

Tags: python

I have to implement results from ansys to python, but when i try demo installation:

```
from ansys.dpf.core import Model
from ansys.dpf.core import examples
model = Model(examples.simple_bar)
print(model)
```

I get "Unable to automatically locate the Ansys path  for version 221. Manually enter one when starting the server or set it as the environment variable "ANSYS_PATH" and a Mechanical APDL that is not responding.

How do I fix this problem?
Tried searching for ANSYS path with:

```
from ansys.mapdl.core.launcher import find_ansys
find_ansys()
```

and it returns

> ('C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\ANSYS
> Student\v211\ansys\bin\winx64\ansys211.exe', 21.1)

Is it connected with the fact that I have ansys 211 and it's searching for ansys 221? Should I reinstall for newer version or I can change the version that it looks for?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same and here is how I resolve it:

1. Just manually reset the ANSYS path by executing the code:

```
from ansys.mapdl.core import launch_mapdl
exec_loc = 'C:/Program Files/ANSYS Inc/ANSYS Student/v222/ANSYS/bin/winx64/ANSYS222.exe'
mapdl = launch_mapdl(exec_loc)
```

2. there might be windows popups requesting for permission to access public networks, just allow

Hope it helps with your case too.

hawkoli1987